# Factorial series $j(D)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n^D)!}$ and hypergeometric functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, computer-algebra, hypergeometric-functions, sage

For positive integer $D$, define $j(D)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n^D)!}$.

For $D \le 6$, sage finds closed form in terms of hypergeometric functions
at algrebraic arguments and fails to find closed form for $D>6$.

According to sage $j(2)= \,_1F_4\left(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ -i + 1,i + 1,-i \, \sqrt{2} + 1,i \, \sqrt{2} + 1 \end{matrix} ; 1 \right)$

The length of the latex sage's closed form of $j(6)$ is 2534
characters long.

Sage's results in machine readable form are [available](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzLsy1LLNJQz1PX5OVysTWyznKxLS7N1TDUT0tMLskvykzM0ciLc9HUydMx1MnP1wTKAwB4Lg74&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Wolfram Alpha can't solve $D>1$ and chatGPT "believes" there isn't simple
closed form for $j(2)$.

> Q1 Are sage's results correct?

> Q2 Is there closed form for $D>6$?

Comment: All these results cannot be true since $(n^2)!$ grows too fast to be expressible by a finite product of pochammer symbols, so no hypergeometric evaluation is possible. In addition, since all the series converge extremely fast, you can immediately check that the result for $D=2$ is numerically wrong.

Comment: for $d=2$ your hypergeometric function evaluates to 1.17227, while the correct answer is 1.04167

Comment: The bug comes from Maxima's simplify_sum command used by Sage, see https://groups.google.com/g/sage-devel/c/E-JooEu5QTo/m/uR3RCXP8AQAJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is in Maxima's `simplify_sum` - which is used by [SageMath](https://sagemath.org)

````
(%i4) load("simplify_sum");
(%o4) "/usr/share/maxima/5.45.1/share/solve_rec/simplify_sum.mac"

(%i5) sum(1/factorial(n^2), n, 1, inf), simpsum;
(%o5) 'sum(1/(n^2)!,n,1,inf)

(%i6) simplify_sum(%);
1/'product(n^2+%,%,1,2*n+1) non-rational term ratio to nusum
1/'product(n^2+%,%,1,2*n+1) non-rational term ratio to nusum
(%o6) %f[1,4]([1],[1-%i,%i+1,1-sqrt(2)*%i,sqrt(2)*%i+1],1)
```
````